# Not able to access https service registered on zookeeper as discovery server via feign client

Tags: ssl, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-zookeeper

I have 2 services registered to zookeeper as discovery server. Both have SSl enabled

I want to access service 1 using a feign client which is in service 2.

I have created a keystore to make the endpoints https in both the services.
Also i have set the spring.cloud.zookeeper.discovery.instance-ssl-port in both the services so that they can be reached over sslPort.

Application.properties for service 1
    `

```
spring.application.name=employee-service
    spring.cloud.zookeeper.discovery.enabled=true
    spring.cloud.zookeeper.connectString=localhost:2181
    spring.cloud.zookeeper.enabled=true
    server.port=7800
    spring.cloud.zookeeper.discovery.instance-ssl-port=7800

    server.ssl.enabled=true
    server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
    server.ssl.key-store=classpath:gpts.p12
    server.ssl.key-store-password=123456
    server.ssl.key-alias= gpts
    server.ssl.protocol=TLS

    ribbon.IsSecure=true
    ribbon.eureka.enabled=false
```

`

```
Application.properties for service 2

spring.application.name=employee-service-feign-client
spring.cloud.zookeeper.discovery.enabled=true
spring.cloud.zookeeper.connectString=localhost:2181
spring.cloud.zookeeper.enabled=true
server.port=7802
spring.cloud.zookeeper.discovery.instance-ssl-port=7802

server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:employee-service.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password=123456
server.ssl.key-alias= employee-service
server.ssl.protocol=TLS

ribbon.IsSecure=true
ribbon.eureka.enabled=false
```

Also i have created the feignClient Bean as below

```
@Configuration
public class CustomFeignConfiguration {

    @LoadBalanced
    @Bean
    public Client feignClient() {
        Client trustSSLSockets = new Client.Default(TrustingSSLSocketFactory.get("employee-service"),
                new NoopHostnameVerifier());
        return trustSSLSockets;
    }
```

Also i have taken the TrustingSSLSocketFactory class from the following location on github https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign/blob/master/core/src/test/java/feign/client/TrustingSSLSocketFactory.java

I have used the feign client annotation like below

```
@FeignClient(value = "employee-service" , configuration=CustomFeignConfiguration.class)
public interface EmployeeFeignController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/employees", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Employee> getEmployees();
```

I have used feign client like below

```
@RestController
@RefreshScope
public class EmployeeInnerController {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeFeignController employeeFeignController;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/feignemployees", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
        return employeeFeignController.getEmployees();
    }
```

I get the following error when i try to hit the following link https://localhost:7082/feignemployees

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: employee-service
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:242) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:339) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1220) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1156) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1050) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:984) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1564) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at feign.Client$Default.convertResponse(Client.java:143) ~[feign-core-10.2.3.jar:na]
    at feign.Client$Default.execute(Client.java:68) ~[feign-core-10.2.3.jar:na]
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:108) ~[feign-core-10.2.3.jar:na]
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:78) ~[feign-core-10.2.3.jar:na]
    at feign.ReflectiveFeign$FeignInvocationHandler.invoke(ReflectiveFeign.java:103) ~[feign-core-10.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy86.getEmployees(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.web.controller.EmployeeInnerController.getEmployees(EmployeeInnerController.java:24) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:282) ~[spring-core-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope$LockedScopedProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GenericScope.java:499) ~[spring-cloud-context-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at com.web.controller.EmployeeInnerController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$62c29e0d.getEmployees(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1039) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_171]
```

Comment: By using a custom feign client, you removed the ribbon feign client. So feign is using `employee-service` as a hostname rather than looking it up in service registry. `@LoadBalanced` only works on `RestTemplate` and `WebClient`.

Comment: @spencergibb is there a way to create custom feign client which is ribbon compliant as well?

Comment: i am able to communicate using the default feign client only if i put the public certificate extracted from my the keystore to jre trusted certificates. Also with a condition that the CN name of the certificate has to same as my machines host name, because in zookeeper the address field is same as my hostname. But in actual production environment the address field will be some IP address and many docker containers will be running with different ip addresses, so my certificate hostname cannot be something static. Please advice how to go about it.

Comment: @spencergibb If i don't use custom feign client and stick to the default one, so the zookeeper will return the http or https when i invoke the feign client? Since i have the property spring.cloud.zookeeper.discovery.instance-ssl-port set for service 1 and also ribbon.IsSecure set to true, so i am assuming that it returns https? is that correct?

Comment: There is a `LoadBalancerFeignClient` that delegates to an http client. You should be able to create an `HttpClient` bean as well and use the defaults.